# getting rid of nesting required for javascript callbacks

Tags: javascript

I've got some javascript functions that take perform asynchronous requests over the network and take a callback to "return" data via.  Here is an example of what this looks like when I use it:

```
RemoteQuery(server,query,function(ret) {
  // do something with ret
})
```

The problem is, if I have several queries in a row the code become quite nested and difficult to manage.  Since I am relying on scoped variables, I can't rip out each of these functions into a separate top-level function either.  Here is a toy example:

```
RemoteQuery(server,query1,function(ret) {
      var x = ret[5]
      RemoteQuery(server,query2,function(ret) {
          var y = ret[3]
          if (x + y > 10) {
              RemoteQuery(server,query2,function(ret) {
                  // do more stuff
              })
          }      
      })
})
```

Obviously if I have more than 2 or 3 queries it starts getting ugly, and I might have a lot more than that!

Ideally, I would like to represent the above without all that nesting, e.g.

```
ret = RemoteQuery(server,query1)
var x = ret[5]
ret = RemoteQuery(server,query2)
var y = ret[3]
if (x + y > 10) {
    ret =RemoteQuery(server,query2)
    // do more stuff
}
```

but the only thing I have thought of that might work would be to parse the javascript, recognize functions which have callbacks, re-write them in the correct form, and eval, but this seems awfully complicated and would make debugging very difficult.

Is there a better mechanism to do this?

Comment: how about an Array of functions?

Comment: jQuery has this `Deferred` technique that can help you, but I don't know if it's ok for you to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'proper' way to do it is to write function declarations for them and avoid relying on the scoped variables (so pass them to each function). Something like:

```
var myFunc1 = function(x, ret1) { 
  RemoteQuery(server, query, function(ret2) { 
    var y = ret[3];
    myFunc2(x, y, ret2);
  });
};

var myFunc2 = function(x, y, ret) { /* do more stuff */ };

RemoteQuery(server, query, function(ret1) {
  var x = ret[5];
  myFunc1(x, ret1);
});
```

Since you have to call those RemoteQuery(ies) asynchronously, there's no way really to do the solution you suggest in your question. Use of the `Deferred` object may do the trick but I think you'd still have to restructure your functions (since you're aiming to avoid the nestedness).

Comment: For anyone referencing this in future, I picked up this model when I learned NodeJS as this is how most of the demo/example apps are built (Node usually requires a lot of nesting).

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use a framework both [JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) as well as [Dojo](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dojo/Deferred.html) (I'm sure others have it too!) contain a deferred object which would be a nice alternative.

Answer (score 0):

How about an array of chained functions?

```
function R1 (server, query, callback)
{
    RemoteQuery(server, query, function(ret) {
        // process ret
        if (x + y > 10)
          callback();
    }
}

function R2 (server, query, callback)
{    
    RemoteQuery(server, query, function(ret) {
        // process ret
        callback();
    }
}

function R3 (server, query, callback)
{
    RemoteQuery(server, query, function(ret) {
        // process ret
        callback();
    }
}

var functions = [R1, R2, R3]

function callAll(a, server, query)
{
    var callNext = function(callback, i)
    {
        if (i < a.length)
            a[i](server, query, function() { callback(callback, i + 1); });
    }
    callNext(callNext, 0);
}

callAll(functions, 'server', 'query');
```

Comment: this way you do not need all those jquerys and dojos etc. ;]